# Getting the address returned as undefined

Tags: solidity

I am trying to run the unit test below and getting the following error:

> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: '0x4ede706B3Fa847c1355D88a64b5F5DB8F6Bd9b6a' == undefined

Here is my unit test:

```
it('rights given to account', async () => {
    await fantasy.methods.giveRightToVote({ from: accounts[0], to: accounts[1] })

    const getRights = await fantasy.methods.getRightsToVote().call({ from : accounts[0] });

    assert.equal(accounts[1], getRights[0]);
    assert.equal(1, getRights.length);
```

Here is my actual smart contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract FantasyLeague {
    // Define address of commissioner
    address public commissioner;
    // Hold votes
    uint[] public proposals;
    // Hold addresses of league members
    address[] public members;
    // Hold addresses of those given votings rights to compare to those who have voted
    address[] public rightsGiven;

    // Deploy contract
    constructor() public payable {
        commissioner = msg.sender;
    }

    function giveRightToVote(address voter) public {
        require(msg.sender == commissioner);
        // Ensures that the right to vote given matches the actual voted addresses
        rightsGiven.push(voter);
    }

    // Propose new team number
    function vote (uint number) public payable {
        // Require ether to reduce fraud
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);
        proposals.push(number);
        members.push(msg.sender);
    }

    // Retrieve List of current proposals
    function getVotes () public view returns (uint[]) {
        return proposals;
    }

    // Retrieve memebrs that have been given right to vote
    function getRightsToVote () public view returns (address[]) {
        return rightsGiven;
    }

    // This function will track the address for every vote cast.  
    //If there are two votes from the same address or a vote from an address not given a right to vote, you know it is invalid
    function getMembers () public view returns (address[]) {
        return members;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you attach code of smart contract then it will be helpful to understand what the exact problem is

Comment: Yeah, at least the text of the `getRightsToVote()` function would be helpful here.  All I can say from that assertion error is that `getRights` is an object or array.

Comment: For sure.  Below is the part of the .sol file.  I am constrained by character limit to put the whole thing, but please let me know if you need more context.  What I am not sure I understand working with web3 is when accessing the contract do you use the contracts native functions, variables etc or make your own in the .test file?

Comment: @ohsully any more feedback now that you have the smart contract below?  Thanks for your help thus far!

Comment: I was able to figure it out.  I needed to pass the right arguments into the giveRightToVote().send() method.  Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, but shouldn't you pass the argument before {from:} object:

`await fantasy.methods.giveRightToVote(accounts[1],{ from: accounts[0])`

Comment: My answer misunderstood where your issue was coming from, I think @desimira is on point -- that's definitely a bug, and it would lead to an undefined value being pushed into that array.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure however can you define getRights outside the "it" testing function?

let getRights;

it('rights given to account', async () => {
    await fantasy.methods.giveRightToVote({ from: accounts[0], to: accounts[1] })

```
getRights = await fantasy.methods.getRightsToVote().call({ from : accounts[0] });

assert.equal(accounts[1], getRights[0]);
assert.equal(1, getRights.length);
```